# How to use a vectorized operation based on column names?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a set-up like this

```
import pandas as pd 

def dummy(val1, val2):
    return val1 * val2 / 10


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 3), 'b': range(2, 4), 'c': range(3, 5)})
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 10}

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```

Now I would like to apply `dummy` to the columns in `df` which exist as keys in `d` and add new columns; thereby `val1` refers to the values in the respective columns and `val2` to the value in `d` for the respective key.

I could do it like this

```
for k, v in d.items():
    # d[k] is of course just v; it's just to show that k is required for both input values
    df[f'{k}_calc'] = dummy(df[k], d[k])
```

which gives me the desired outcome

```
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc
0  1  2  3     0.3     2.0
1  2  3  4     0.6     3.0
```

Is there a more straightforward implementation available that avoids the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

<strike>cols = pd.Index(['a','b'])</strike>

```
#Using @richardec idea of the dictionary keys
cols = pd.Index(d.keys())
df[cols + '_calc'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: dummy(x, d[x.name]))
df
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc
0  1  2  3     0.3     2.0
1  2  3  4     0.6     3.0
```

#### Details:

- Using pd.DataFrame.apply, you are passing each column of the
  dataframe into the lambda.
- x.name is the column header.
- Using x, and d[x.name] as inputs to your custom function.

Comment: Ah, nice, did not know about `.name` (upvoted).

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `apply` vectorized?  I am seeing online it is not vectorized or yes it is.

Comment: @Emma Well... apply in this way using pass each column of the dataframe into the function.  You are vectorized for each column of the dataframe.  Here, you are not looping of each row.  Now if you used apply with axis=1, then this is not vectorized.  You would then be looping over each row of the dataframe.

Comment: Ah I see. that makes sense!  Series.apply vs Dataframe.apply(with axis=1) determines whether it is vectorized or not.  Cool, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Calling a function for each row inevitable will lead to row-by-row execution one way or the other. But, you can do some things to make it more pandas-esque:

I was thinking that it could be done with `agg`, but I actually don't think so because agg can't use different pass different values to the aggregation functions based on the column. So using `apply`:

```
tmp = df[d.keys()].apply(lambda col: dummy(col, d[col.name])).add_suffix('_calc')
df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc
0  1  2  3     0.3     2.0
1  2  3  4     0.6     3.0
```

Note the use of `add_suffix` to add suffixes to the column names.

Comment: Thanks, similar to Scott's answer (also upvoted).

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now. But still, mine has different and additional information (and can be one-lined more cleanly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the dictionary to Series to benefit from broadcasting and index alignment:

```
s = pd.Series(d)

df.join((df.reindex(columns=s.index)*s/10).add_suffix('_calc'))
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  a_calc  b_calc
0  1  2  3     0.3     2.0
1  2  3  4     0.6     3.0
```

Comment: How would you do it using `dummy` (actual function is more difficult, so hardcoding the `/10` would not work.

Comment: @Cleb How more difficult would be the actual "/10"? Can you give a more realistic example?